# ps4 controller working only in safe mode and remote on pc

Tags: controllers, ps4

Yestarday was all good. Ps4 usb ports are fine becouse i can swap between options in safe mode and there's a white light . Controller is fine as well becouse i played on ps4 remote with blue light on. I cant start ps4 with ps4 button neither there's no light on the controller.I cant restart settings becouse it requires connection with ps4 via cable and it doesnt recognise at blue screen. Dont want to spend 30pounds for a new controller if it's working.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Is your controller not working wirelessly, only wired? Is it not working at all?

Comment: It works only when using the cable and only in safe mode and remote play. Safe mode- white light on the controller, remote play on pc works normally and i have blue light. I have no light at mo controller either its connected via cable to ps4 or without.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the controller? There should be a hole on the back of the controller that has a button inside of it by one of the screws. You'll need to use a pin to hit it.

Comment: Tried like 10 times didnt help.

Comment: i am able to log into ps4 via pc using remote play with controlller connected into pc. Using wifi and it works. Might be damaged bluetooth in ps4. No idea

Comment: What's the actual question? I don't even see a single question mark..

Comment: Thinking loudly buddy...  trying to find some kind of  a solution.